# Elastic search - Java api to search on multiple fields not giving exact results

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am search my input keyword in multiple field using java api `QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery` its not giving me exact results. Its giving some random results which is not relavant to my search query.

Please find my code below.

```
SearchRequest contentSearchRequest = new SearchRequest(ATTACHMENT); 
SearchSourceBuilder contentSearchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
contentSearchRequest.types(TYPE);
MultiMatchQueryBuilder attachmentQB = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(keyword, "attachment.content","catalog_keywords","product_keywords");
contentSearchSourceBuilder.query(attachmentQB);
contentSearchSourceBuilder.size(5);
```

Please find my mapping details :

```
PUT document_attachment
    {

         "settings": {
         "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "custom_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace",
              "char_filter": [
                "html_strip"
              ],
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ]
            },
            "product_catalog_keywords_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace",
              "char_filter": [
                "html_strip"
              ],
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },

      "mappings" : {
        "doc" : {
          "properties" : {
            "attachment" : {
              "properties" : {
                "content" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
                },
                "content_length" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "content_type" : {
                  "type" : "text"
                },
                "language" : {
                  "type" : "text"
                }
              }
            },
            "fileContent" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "id": {
            "type": "long"
            },
            "catalog_keywords" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer": "product_catalog_keywords_analyzer"
            },
            "product_keywords" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer": "product_catalog_keywords_analyzer"
            },

          }
        }
      }
    }
```